# Browser does not detect changes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

Im developing an AngularJS application using IDE WebStorm and Safari browser.

Everything has worked perfectly so far, but I recently encapsulated some HTLM in a template that I use via a directive:

```
 .directive('referenceValue', [function ($scope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "views/citizenprofile/reference/reference.html",
        controller: "referenceValueCtrl"
    }
}])
```

I "call" the directive the normal way, nothing fancy `<reference-value></reference-value>`

When I edit the reference.html the browser only detects the changes **in the first edit.**. If I edit reference.html a second time and update the browser then the change is not detected. If I restart the browser the change is detected again. So I basically need to restart my browser each time I want to debug the HTML code. 
Changes in the Controller is detected at every edit.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Open browser console(F12) -> click the upper right corner gear(Settings) -> Check "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". Leave the console opened while you debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is being cached. There are a couple of work arounds. Either use Chrome's dev tools to disable cache when the dev tools is open, or use the `$templateCache.remove()` in your application.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
   $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      $templateCache.removeAll();
   });
});
```

Find more info on removing the template cache [here](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.com/2014/02/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs.html).

Comment: It is a question about cache. When I remove cache it works again. Thanks for the tip.
Unfortunately Im using Safari so the $templateCache.removeAll(); does not work.

Comment: `$templateCache.removeAll()` is angular specific and not browser specific. The Dev tools cache disabling method is browser specific, but Safari dev tools also has an option to disable cache under `Develop->Disable Cache`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using google chrome press CTRL+SHIF+J and on the network tab check 'Disable Cache'

Hope it helps