# Angular new changes not reflecting

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter, caching

I am building a new project using angularjs and PHP(codeigniter).
I am facing an issue with the content or changes I make on both client-and serverside, but the changes are not being reflected.

Does this have something to do with the cache?

Comment: Try **Ctrl + F5** in browser.

Comment: If you are on mac try, Shift+Cmd+R, on Windows Shift+F5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser uses template caching, which should be cleared upon making changes to templates. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33040730/browser-does-not-detect-changes-in-angularjs). You can do the following to make your life easier when developing:

### Reload the page with clearing cache each time you need to update your app

Yet a more convenient way is to:

### Disable cache in developer tools

E.g. for Chrome

> CTRL+SHIF+J and on the network tab check 'Disable Cache'

Yet may be better still to:

### Remove template cache in your application

This is done via `$templateCache.remove()`

[More info on preventing template caching](http://oncodesign.io/2014/02/19/safely-prevent-template-caching-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you are also having issue with Angular default change detection mechanism. In my case, in my ionic4 Project default change mechanism of Angular was somewhat not working properly so I triggered it manually.

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    ref.detach();
    setInterval(() => {
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    }, 500);
 }
```